# Kernel Panic on Late 2012 iMac

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic

I keep getting a Kernel Panic on my Late 2012 iMac. My log is at http://pastebin.com/AbqrgeGk if you need it. Please help. Thanks!

Log imported:

```
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8022c17cc2): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7fa4e29627, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x00000000000001c3, CR3: 0x00000005eb737017, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0x000000000000259b, RDX: 0xffffff82fd72b78f
RSP: 0xffffff82fd72b750, RBP: 0xffffff82fd72b7e0, RSI: 0xffffff807a928508, RDI: 0x0000000000e00000
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x0000000000e00000, R10: 0x0000000000000001, R11: 0x000000001cffd000
R12: 0xffffff80542a0078, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 0xffffff80542a0000
RFL: 0x0000000000010297, RIP: 0xffffff7fa4e29627, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x00000000000001c3, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff82fd72b400 : 0xffffff8022b2bda1 
0xffffff82fd72b480 : 0xffffff8022c17cc2 
0xffffff82fd72b640 : 0xffffff8022c34b73 
0xffffff82fd72b660 : 0xffffff7fa4e29627 
0xffffff82fd72b7e0 : 0xffffff7fa4e289c4 
0xffffff82fd72b8a0 : 0xffffff7fa4e3fd0f 
0xffffff82fd72b900 : 0xffffff7fa4daabc8 
0xffffff82fd72b920 : 0xffffff7fa4e3ff2b 
0xffffff82fd72b940 : 0xffffff7fa4d73995 
0xffffff82fd72b960 : 0xffffff7fa4da8fcc 
0xffffff82fd72b980 : 0xffffff7fa4d8c944 
0xffffff82fd72b9a0 : 0xffffff7fa4e37928 
0xffffff82fd72b9c0 : 0xffffff7fa4d7bfdd 
0xffffff82fd72ba00 : 0xffffff7fa4d8613b 
0xffffff82fd72ba50 : 0xffffff7fa4e166af 
0xffffff82fd72baa0 : 0xffffff7fa4d76db2 
0xffffff82fd72bb30 : 0xffffff8023101192 
0xffffff82fd72bb60 : 0xffffff8023101d89 
0xffffff82fd72bbc0 : 0xffffff80230ff503 
0xffffff82fd72bd00 : 0xffffff8022be21e7 
0xffffff82fd72be10 : 0xffffff8022b3000c 
0xffffff82fd72be40 : 0xffffff8022b149f3 
0xffffff82fd72be90 : 0xffffff8022b2531d 
0xffffff82fd72bf10 : 0xffffff8022c031ea 
0xffffff82fd72bfb0 : 0xffffff8022c35396 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(156.16)[8DA5CE1F-2C00-3CE3-8BF1-1FC07BFCF4E7]@0xffffff7fa4d72000->0xffffff7fa4de0fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[D8F585E8-2EE9-3135-8E37-A034123FE45C]@0xffffff7fa3324000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6F7F093D-DBEA-356A-9A08-D8EAC7F767DE]@0xffffff7fa36c0000
         com.apple.GeForce(10.0.4)[84C92A5B-73D3-33C4-9A69-9CE32825816C]@0xffffff7fa4def000->0xffffff7fa4e85fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[D8F585E8-2EE9-3135-8E37-A034123FE45C]@0xffffff7fa3324000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[161AE366-94FE-3E53-8ABD-78A603351329]@0xffffff7fa3707000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.0.4)[95736EED-9154-3CBF-B639-6038E7128035]@0xffffff7fa371e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6F7F093D-DBEA-356A-9A08-D8EAC7F767DE]@0xffffff7fa36c0000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(156.16)[8DA5CE1F-2C00-3CE3-8BF1-1FC07BFCF4E7]@0xffffff7fa4d72000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer
Boot args: kext-dev-mode=1

Mac OS version:
14E46

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.4.0: Thu May 28 11:35:04 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.30.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: E3C26B2F-8B97-3F1D-B193-690F7E34F830
Kernel slide:     0x0000000022800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8022a00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8022900000
System model name: iMac13,2 (Mac-FC02E91DDD3FA6A4)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 44580138197358
last loaded kext at 24956806443330: com.vmware.kext.vmioplug.14.1.4 14.1.4 (addr 0xffffff7fa597f000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 9756798243089: com.vmware.kext.vmci   90.6.3 (addr 0xffffff7fa5945000, size 69632)
loaded kexts:
com.vmware.kext.vmioplug.14.1.4 14.1.4
com.vmware.kext.vmx86   0277.92.24
com.vmware.kext.vmnet   0277.92.24
com.vmware.kext.vsockets    90.6.0
com.vmware.kext.vmci    90.6.3
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.3.16
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  4.3.16
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.3.16
com.nvidia.CUDA 1.1.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.3.16
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    1.1.1
com.wavtap.driver.WavTap    0.4.0
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    1.6.6
com.ScreamingBee.driver.SBVirtualMic64  1.1.0
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.6
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.2.0d4
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   85.3
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.5f8
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.18.1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18.1
com.apple.GeForce   10.0.4
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.7.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.12
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.5f8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.0.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   930.37.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  176.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   176.2
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.3.5f8
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  264.6
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.0.4
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18.1
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.5f8
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.5f8
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.16
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.24
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 397
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
```

Comment: Did you try Safr mode ? What is the recent app you have installed (after that you are getting panic)? Uninstall the app and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would try would be to uninstall Soundflower & see if things improve. 
I had no end of trouble with it in recent versions, & eventually just learned to live without it.

There's a script in the .dmg to uninstall it automatically.

If you don't have it, you can get it from https://code.google.com/p/soundflower/downloads/detail?name=Soundflower-1.6.6b.dmg

If you really need the internal routing facility & can't use existing structures like ReWire, paid alternatives are:-

- Rogue Amoeba's [Audio Hijack](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) - simple pictorial internal routing, far more comprehensive than soundflower, but doesn't specifically use multi-channel routing afaik & isn't specifically designed just to route, but to be its own recorder
- [Plogue Bidule](http://www.plogue.com/products/bidule/) - which is capable of routing your brain to your navel, using your fridge & the current windspeed as modulators [not really, but it's ridiculously comprehensive]... if you can figure the darn thing out ;-)